# NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(Object)" because "this.objectMapper" is null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot-test, objectmapper

My unit test is getting the error "this.objectMapper" is null"... I have marked the objectMapper with @Autowired annotation.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(Object)" because "this.objectMapper" is null

    at com.santiang.demokadaiden.api.ProductCategoryMasterControllerTest.saveProductCategory(ProductCategoryMasterControllerTest.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ProductCategoryMasterControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private ProductCategoryMaster productCategoryMaster;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    void saveProductCategory() throws Exception {
        ProductCategoryDTO categoryDTO = new ProductCategoryDTO();
        categoryDTO.setId(1L);
        categoryDTO.setName("Category 1");

        ProductCategory savedCategory = new ProductCategory(1L, "Category 1");

        given(productCategoryMaster.saveProductCategory(any(ProductCategory.class))).willReturn(savedCategory);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/product-categories")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(categoryDTO)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(1))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Category 1"));
    }
```

can anyone help me with my code?

Comment: Do not edit a question that received an answer to ask an entirely different question. I have rolled back your edit. If you have a different question, then create a **new** question.

Answer (score 0):

`objectMapper` was never initialized. You will need to instantiate `objectMapper` as a `new ObjectMapper` and then you will be able to call its methods. While it's not initialize it properly, its value is `null`, that is unknown/undefined/nil and you cannot invoke methods of `null`.

Comment: Arpas. where I have to initialise the objectMapper so that it is not null anymore

Comment: @Artyudi you need to initialize it before you call `writeValueAsString`. For example inside `saveProductCategory` but above that part of the code.

Comment: @BeforeAll annotation for JUnit should do nicely for initializing the objectmapper

Comment: @BIBOO unit 1998X I have initialised the ObjectMapper in the BeforeAll annotation but it still doesn't work, I can't call the objectMapper...

Comment: @Artyudi can you edit your question and show us how you tried it?

Comment: @LajosArpad objectMapper and mockMvc error problems have been resolved, now a new error appears java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.id" expected:<1> but was:<9>, I'm really confused